# How can I get the index of next non-NaN number with series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

In pandas, I am now looping with an instance of Series, is it possible for me to know the index of the next non-NaN instantly when I meet a NaN. I don't want to skip those NaNs, because I want to do the interpolation against them.

e.g now I have a Series `a` with elements

```
5, 6, 5, NaN, NaN, NaN, 7, 8, 9, NaN, NaN, NaN, 10, 10
```

The indexes of them is from 0 to 13, when I iterating the Series, when would simply love to know what is the index of the next NaN, and what is the next non-NaN. So from the beginning, can I instantly know the index of the first NaN is 4? Then when I jump to a[4], I need to know the index of the next non-NaN number, which is 6 in this case.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`isnull`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiS95y57enKAhVGCZoKHTn6BKQQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.isnull.html&usg=AFQjCNF-zsbxBhTegthKXtMm3fDGC13IvQ&bvm=bv.113943665,d.bGs) method to find in what indices you have `NaN` values and then for current step you could compare your index with the next:

```
In [48]: s.index[s.isnull()]
Out[48]: Int64Index([3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11], dtype='int64')
```

You could also use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) to find first non `NaN` value, e.g.:

```
In [49]: s[4:]
Out[49]:
4    NaN
5    NaN
6      7
7      8
8      9
9    NaN
10   NaN
11   NaN
12    10
13    10
dtype: float64

In [50]: s[4:].first_valid_index()
Out[50]: 6
```

**EDIT**

If you want to an integer index you could use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) of the pandas indices:

```
b = s[4:]

In [156]: b
Out[156]:
4    NaN
5    NaN
6      7
7      8
8      9
9    NaN
10   NaN
11   NaN
12    10
13    10
dtype: float64

In [157]: b.first_valid_index()
Out[157]: 6

In [158]: b.index.get_loc(b.first_valid_index())
Out[158]: 2
```

**EDIT2**

You could use [`get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) to get all indices where you have `NaNs` and where you have valid values:

```
import string
s = pd.Series([5, 6, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 8, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 10], index = list(string.ascii_letters[:len(s.index)]))

In [216]: s
Out[216]:
a     5
b     6
c     5
d   NaN
e   NaN
f   NaN
g     7
h     8
i     9
j   NaN
k   NaN
l   NaN
m    10
n    10
dtype: float64

valid_indx = s.index.get_indexer(s.index[~s.isnull()])
nan_indx = s.index.get_indexer(s.index[s.isnull()])

In [220]: valid_indx
Out[220]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8, 12, 13])

In [221]: nan_indx
Out[221]: array([ 3,  4,  5,  9, 10, 11])
```

Or the simplest way will be with [`np.where`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPk7OK_enKAhWEQZoKHaCMByAQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.scipy.org%2Fdoc%2Fnumpy-1.10.1%2Freference%2Fgenerated%2Fnumpy.where.html&usg=AFQjCNHCHvylDtvkAJDUMbo2IKe5KyhKSA):

```
In [222]: np.where(s.isnull())
Out[222]: (array([ 3,  4,  5,  9, 10, 11], dtype=int32),)

In [223]: np.where(~s.isnull())
Out[223]: (array([ 0,  1,  2,  6,  7,  8, 12, 13], dtype=int32),)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I get the integer index instead of the indexes defined by myself?

Comment: @xxx222 I think you could do `reset_index(drop=True)` to make you indices started from 0. Or do you need that indices for something else also?

Comment: Yes, and I want to return an interpolated Series after then (so I want to keep those indexes).

Comment: Thank you! And I still want to ask is there any way I can calculate between two non-integer indexes? Since in this case getting the integer location of the first valid index does not allow me to calculate the distance of the NaN gap.

Comment: @xxx222 another attempt... Take a look to `np.where`