# Find 'next' non-null value in column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to create a new column which appends the row index of next non-null value next to the current non-null value using the following df as a starting point:

```
ts = [
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-19 22:01:22.229', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-19 23:32:08.109', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-20 02:50:22.181', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-20 06:12:44.249', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-20 19:27:22.129', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-21 11:39:08.119', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-21 16:59:22.610', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        ]

score = [ np.nan, np.nan, 77.692, np.nan, 77.709, np.nan, 76.145 ]


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': ts, 'jack': score})
```

The output would look like this:

```
                     date    jack  nxt_nn_value
0 2016-06-19 22:01:22.229     NaN           NaN
1 2016-06-19 23:32:08.109     NaN           NaN
2 2016-06-20 02:50:22.181  77.692             4
3 2016-06-20 06:12:44.249     NaN           NaN
4 2016-06-20 19:27:22.129  77.709             6
5 2016-06-21 11:39:08.119     NaN           NaN
6 2016-06-21 16:59:22.610  76.145           NaN
```

I have found a link that touches on the issue but I could not adapt to suit..
[How can I get the index of next non-NaN number with series in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283817/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-next-non-nan-number-with-series-in-pandas)

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find the [`notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notnull.html) values in `jack`. Then [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) up. Then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to assign the results, and [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html) to break index alignment:

```
m = df['jack'].notnull()
df.loc[m, 'nxt_nn_value'] = pd.Series(m[m].index).shift(-1).values
```

`df`:

```
                     date    jack  nxt_nn_value
0 2016-06-19 22:01:22.229     NaN           NaN
1 2016-06-19 23:32:08.109     NaN           NaN
2 2016-06-20 22:50:22.181  77.692           4.0
3 2016-06-20 06:12:44.249     NaN           NaN
4 2016-06-20 19:27:22.129  77.709           6.0
5 2016-06-21 11:39:08.119     NaN           NaN
6 2016-06-21 16:59:22.610  76.145           NaN
```

---

Explanation:

First find where the values in `jack` are `notnull`:

```
m = df['jack'].notnull()

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
Name: jack, dtype: bool
```

Filter to get the index there are many equivalent ways to do this:

```
m[m].index

Int64Index([2, 4, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Then convert to a Series so it can be shifted this will give the "next" index:

```
pd.Series(m[m].index).shift(-1)

0    4.0
1    6.0
2    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Then assign back to the DataFrame only where values are `notnull`, `values` is needed to break index alignment between the Series and the DataFrame:

```
df.loc[m, 'nxt_nn_value'] = pd.Series(m[m].index).shift(-1).values
```

Comment: The explanation is like gold. Thank  you I am new to this and concise narrative like that is much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: is this the best method for a dictionary of dataframes with over 10000 rows each?

Comment: I don't know how to quantify "best" as I don't have anything to compare with, however, I found that on a dataframe of 20,000 rows it takes about 100ms to complete. For 10,000 rows it was `64.9624 ms`. Assuming the DataFrames are in that range this would mean 10-18 per second.

Comment: cheers. I have a further adaption I would like to make to the df following this but i will open as new question within the next 5 mins so that this one can be closed